# PHP, How can I retrieve a specific number?

Tags: php

I need to retrieve itunes app id from the URL address.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds-star-wars/id557137623?mt=8

I used strpos(), but this one didn't work.

How can I get numbers after id from this address?

$url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds-star-wars/id557137623?mt=8';

$result = '557137623'

result will be like this one.

Comment: Go for Regular expressions http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @YousufIqbal To put a url in comments, its `[name](url)`.

Comment: you can do this with strpos (though not necessary the best tool).. show us your code

Comment: what's the reason that I can minus points for this question? Is it because I didn't put my entire codes? I thought it was better to explain what I was looking for. I looked up the PHP command, but couldn't make it.

Comment: I think, it's because people at stackoverflow tend to be a little pissed off when RegEx questions appear again ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds-star-wars/id557137623?mt=8';
preg_match("~id(\d+)~", $url, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
echo $result; //557137623
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Find where the / is and add 2 for the word "id"
$pos = strrpos($url, "/") + 2; // Note that it's "strrpos" not "strpos"

// Find the question mark at the end
$pos2 = strpos($url, "?");

$id = substr($url, $pos, $pos2 - $pos);
```

This is, of course, assuming your URL always has this form.